# Which online tool or app would you recommend for self time management?

Tags: calendar, time-management, task-management

I'm a manager looking for a tool to help me organize my various tasks and attaching timeboxes on them.

The ideal tool would allow me to:

- create a timeline of tasks
- attach descriptions/documents to tasks
- notify my of upcoming tasks

Optionally, it would be nice to be also able to:

- group/categorize my tasks
- comment on tasks
- be able to see archived/finished tasks

I suppose I could use Google Calendar for this for free in a way, but I was wondering what your recommendations would be.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Clockify](https://clockify.me/), you can group tasks/projects and add/track time. It's free and has great graphs to show where you spend your time.

I haven't setup a timeline but belive the option is available and can be used for notifying.